# Convert linq to SQL

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

Does anyone know how to translate this? When I hit the debugger I get 3 different queries and var contains an array of results. I am trying to replace that line with a method that will call a stored procedure but I do not understand what the query should be. Thanks a lot

```
var restbl =
        context.tbl_one.FirstOrDefault(d => d.qty < d.tbl_two.Count(a => !a.tbl_three.ust))
     ?? context.tbl_one.FirstOrDefault(d => d.qty > d.tbl_two.Count(a => !a.tbl_three.ust));


{SELECT
`Extent1`.`id`, 
`Extent1`.`name`, 
`Extent1`.`qty`, 
`Extent1`.`cdate`
FROM `tbl_one` AS `Extent1`}

{SELECT
`Extent1`.`id`, 
`Extent1`.`tbl_one_id`, 
`Extent1`.`tbl_three_id`, 
`Extent1`.`enabled`
FROM `tbl_two` AS `Extent1`}

{SELECT
`Extent1`.`id`, 
`Extent1`.`ttid`, 
`Extent1`.`code`, 
`Extent1`.`cdate`, 
`Extent1`.`mdate`, 
`Extent1`.`prt`, 
`Extent1`.`ust`
FROM `tbl_three` AS `Extent1`}

var countToAdd = restbl.qty - context.tbl_two.Count(a => a.tbl_one_id == restbl.id && !a.tbl_three.ust);
```

Comment: You should refactor the LINQ statement into `context.tbl_one.FirstOrDefault(d => firstCondition || secondCondition)`. That will be one SQL statement.

Comment: But do the conditions make sense? Isn't it the same as `qty != count`?

Comment: Thanks @GertArnold, sorry my linq understanding is pretty bad. I always use store procedures and avoid using linq. I know many would say I should use linq instead but it is much easier for me to use straight sql and just create a method to call it. The conditions do make sense, the program works fine, I'm just trying to replace the edmx and linq.

Comment: I'm sure it works, but I think the conditions can be simplified as I indicated above.

Comment: You can use linqpad

Comment: thanks @linqpad, I will try that now

Answer (score 1):

You can use LINQPad or Linquer tool for easily converting your linq query to SQL or vice versa. They are very helpful in converting complex queries.

Answer (score 0):

My assumption would be: (assuming you use MSSQL)

```
result= SELECT TOP 1 FROM tbl_one t1 WHERE t1.qty< (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_two t2 INNER JOIN tbl_three t3 ON t3.id=t2.tbl_three_id WHERE t3.ust = 0 AND t1.id=t2.tbl_one-id)

if (result IS NULL)
result= SELECT TOP 1 FROM tbl_one t1 WHERE t1.qty> (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_two t2 INNER JOIN tbl_three t3 ON t3.id=t2.tbl_three_id WHERE t3.ust = 0 AND t1.id=t2.tbl_one-id)
```

Comment: Thank you so much @olealbers, this is of great help and I will try this as smoking is coming out of my head at the moment :(. I am using MySQL instead of MSSQL but I guess syntax will be very similar.

Comment: do you happen to know the correct query for the var countToAdd? thanks a lot